# Unable to install all pip packages

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to remove Python 2.7 from my machine. following instructions from another post to remove all pip packages I ran the following:

```
 sudo pip freeze | grep -v "^-e" | xargs sudo pip uninstall -y
```

While this removed some packages I got the following message for many more:

```
Not uninstalling rpi.gpio at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
Can't uninstall 'RPi.GPIO'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

Q1: Do i need to remove all these packages before uninstalling Python 2.7?

Q2: If so, how can I do it?

Comment: How about just deleting whatever is left of `/usr/lib/python2.7/` after first removing any python packages that are provided via your operating system's package manager?